# MSDN documentation wrong about Directory.Delete?

Tags: c#, msdn

In the MSDN documentation for System.IO.Directory.Delete(string, bool) ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) it says that `DirectoryNotFoundException` is thrown when "path refers to a file instead of a directory.".

However, the following test fails because IOException is thrown:

```
[Test]
[ExpectedException(typeof(DirectoryNotFoundException))] // because DeleteDirectory fails on files.
public void DeleteFileWithDeleteDirectoryDirectly()
{
    var tempPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "MyTestDirectory");
    Directory.CreateDirectory(tempPath);
    string file = Path.Combine(tempPath, "File1235.txt");
    CreateDummyFile(file);
    Assert.That(File.Exists(file));
    Directory.Delete(file, true);
}
```

with

```
void CreateDummyFile(string name)
{
    FileStream fs = File.Open(name, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    fs.WriteByte(255);
    fs.Close();
}
```

(tempPath is deleted after each test in the real code, the above is shortened for illustration). Is my test to force this error wrong or is the documentation not correct?

Comment: Can't reproduce here. IOException thrown

Comment: That's what I'm saying. IOException is thrown but DirectoryNotFoundException is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the documentation is right, but there is a trick.
When you call DeleteDirectory passing an existent file the first exception thrown is a

> IOException ...... A file with the same name and location specified by path
>   exists.

You can prove this with

```
var tempFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "MyTestDirectory", "inexistentfile.txt");
var tempPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "MyTestDirectory");
Directory.CreateDirectory(tempPath);
string file = Path.Combine(tempPath, "File1235.txt");
CreateDummyFile(file);
if(File.Exists(file)) Console.WriteLine("File exists");
Directory.Delete(tempFile, true);
```

Now, if you try to pass a file name that doesn't exist the exception `DirectoryNotFoundException` is thrown as expected.

Comment: Yea, that's it. Confusing behavior still.

Answer (score 0):

The file that you are attempting to delete is not a directory and io exception is thrown because "A file with the same name and location specified by path exists." Which is one of ioexception listed reasons